# Why cant print 2 char with sysem.out.print command

Tags: java

I cant print two char in one system.out.print code as it is shown in below. I would like to know how java works in that case since it is summing up ASCII conversions of these chars.

```
System.out.println('a'+'b');
```

Comment: For reference: [JLS Table 2.11.1-B](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1-320) shows the actual runtime-types of java primitives. Since `char`s are `int`s (at runtime), the addition adds the ASCII (or, to be more precise, the Unicode-values).

Comment: Try `System.out.println(""+'a'+'b');`

Comment: or just `System.out.println("ab");` ??! [:-)

Answer (score 3):

This is Java,
not JavaScript.

In Java,
the single quote is reserved for char data.
You must use the double quote for a String value.

As stated in the @Sean Bright comment,
char + char is math, not string concatenation.

There are many ways to output two char values.
Here is an example of one such way:

```
final String output;

output = String.format("%c %c\n", 'a', 'b');

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: maybe without the space between both `%c`s; and no `\n` since already using `println`, even better, use `printf` (with `\n` or `%n`) directly

Answer (score 0):

The output of the last one is 195, because you are doing an addition of char values in the ASCII table (97+98)
.
you first sum all the values as explained before, then convert it to a String adding "" to the sum of the ASCII values of the chars. However, the println method expect a Strin
Y

Comment: Java's (as well as VB4/5/6/A/Script, JavaScript, .NET, etc) char and string datatypes use the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set; Not ASCII.