# why letter's ASCII were converted automatically by method .toCharArray()?

Tags: java, arrays

all.

I think I can only understand one way to make count[128] mark the string's characters' occurences:

if s string characters are all lowercase, then it comes to :

```
for(char c: s.toCharArray())  count[c-'a']++;
```

If they are all uppercase,

```
for(char c: S.toCharArray())  count[c-'A']++;
```

But I can't make sense how does this way to mark the character directly into int indexes?

```
for(char c: s.toCharArray())    count[c]++;
```

From my understanding, is it count['A'] making sense?

Comment: `char` is a numerical type. That's why you can subtract from it.

Comment: What are the indices which you actually want?  What is the index for `a`?  What about `A`?

Comment: yes, it is making sense (as using subtraction in `c-'a'`) - `char` is an integral type ([JLS 4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)) in Java so it can be used as an index or in arithmetics

Comment: also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57265562/85421) asked yesterday and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57226439/85421) and linked questions

Comment: `From my understanding, is it count['A'] making sense` Yes, makes sense.  Note that `'A'` is not the same as `"A"`.  `'A'` is an integer type just like `int` and `long`.  So it can be used anywhere an `int` can (with some provisos and exceptions for widening and narrowing operations). See the ASCII chart below, `count['A']` is the same as `count[65]` (on the chart below, A = 65).

Answer (score 0):

The int index represents that character's position in the ANSI character table.

Answer (score 0):

Each character actually a number and each number represents a symbol. Have a look at this table:
[image]

Here : Character index **[97-122] represents [A-Z]** and **[65-90] represents [a-z]**, also **[48-57] represents ['0'-'9']**. such as

```
'A' = 65
'B' = 66
'C' = 67
 ...
 ...
'Z' = 90
```

So `count['a']` actually `count[97]`, `count['A']` actually `count[65]`.